# Purely discrete spectrum of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics

Let $(H,D(H))$ be a self-adjoint operator on the infinite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ that is bounded below and also assume that $$\text{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}}(e^{-H})<\infty \, .$$

How can I see that $H$ has purely discrete spectrum and that the sequence of eigenvalues $e_0\leq e_1\leq e_2\leq...$ repeated according to multiplicity is unbounded? And moreover why is $\text{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}}\left(e^{-\beta(H-\mu)}\right)<\infty$ for $\beta>0$ and $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Definitely a question for [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175280/when-is-the-spectrum-of-the-hamiltonian-purely-continuous
And this paper might be interesting to you: http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/158.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try to give you some points, perhaps someone else can post proofs or fill some gaps if you need them (the proofs are not easy).

1. $\text{Tr}_{\mathcal H} \left(e^{-H}\right) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\langle e_n, e^{-H}e_{n}\right\rangle <+\infty $ means that the exponential of the negative Hamiltonian is an operator of finite trace, thus bounded. If you assume the trace is the same for all infinite countable bases in $\mathcal{H}$, then the operator $e^{-H}$ is [trace class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class).
2. A trace class self-adjoint operator has a pure point spectrum. This is Theorem 8.6 of [Prugovecki, 2nd. Ed., p.387](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486453278). This is proven using the spectral theorem.
3. Using the spectral theorem and the functional calculus (which works because $e^{-x}$ is bounded for $x>0$), if $e^{-H}$ is bounded with a pure point spectrum (the content of point 2.), then $H$ has a pure point spectrum.
4. In the proof of theorem 8.7 further below in his text, Prugovecki makes the following argument:

$$ H = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda ~ dE_{\lambda} ^{H} = \sum_{\lambda ~ \in\sigma(H)} \lambda E^H(\{\lambda\}) \tag{1}$$

(the sum is uniformly convergent). Each characteristic subspace $M_\lambda$ which corresponds to a non-zero eigenvalue of $H$ is finite-dimensional.

5. Then we can employ a version of the [minimax principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Self-adjoint_operators) quoted as preposition 3.5.5 from page 64 of David Ruelle's [Rigorous Stat. Mech.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805383603) book.
   This is a little more general than needed (the Hamiltonian would suffice to be symmetric, but in this case, it is assumed directly self-adjoint).

[image]

This proves the fact that the spectral values of the Hamiltonian are increasing.
Another proof for the spectral properties of the Hamiltonian would have been from the fact that $e^{-H}$ is completely continuous (from being trace-class), hence its spectrum would also be pure point and decreasing. $e^{H}$ is the inverse of $e^{-H}$, so its spectrum would again be pure point but increasing, and the same goes for the spectrum of $H$.

6. Points 1.-5. show that asking for the Hamiltonian to be bounded and with a pure point spectrum is a consequence of supposing that the quantum canonical partition function $Z$ be well-defined as a trace class operator, which is a very stringent requirement. The converse is not true in general. [link math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776356/show-e-ta-is-a-trace-class-operator-t0). However, the partition function for the harmonic oscillator is well-defined, see the proof here: [Proof that $\exp(-\beta H)$ is a trace-class operator for the harmonic oscillator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452042/proof-exp-beta-h-trace-class-operator)
7. Your last point assumes the fact that the canonical partition function $Z$ is well-defined and questions why is this also well-defined as a trace class operator in case the system has a shift in ground energy and the rest of its spectrum (at least this is what I make from your deduction of a constant from the Hamiltonian). Well, this is easy because the spectral properties of $H-\mu \hat{1}$ for constant $\mu$ are the same (pure point and increasing). Also, $\beta >0$ to keep the whole operator trace class. Also, $\mu$ must be real, else the sum with the Hamiltonian is not self-adjoint.

Comment: okay wow, this is a lot more complicated than i expected! thank you very much for your deteailed answer! I looked at the proofs in Prugovecki and now try to understand them.

Comment: Yes, ironically, stat. mech. textbooks simply assume that for a Hamiltonian $H$ the density operator and partition function simply exist, but that's not really true. You need to prove that the $\exp{(-\beta H)}$ exists as a trace class operator.